# Best way to access class-method into instance method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class-method

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def testmethod(self):
        # instance method
        self.task(10)      # type-1 access class method

        cls = self.__class__ 
        cls.task(20)        # type-2 access class method 

    @classmethod 
    def task(cls,val)
        print(val)
```

I have two way to access class method into instance method.

```
self.task(10)
```

or

```
cls = self.__class__
cls.task(20)
```

My question is which one is the best and why??

If both ways are not same, then which one I use in which condition?

Comment: You can also just directly call `Test.task(20)` from within that method, instead of your two-liner.

Comment: @xgord: yes but the two are *not* equivalent. `Task.task(20)` will always call the `task` defined in `Task` whereas a *subclass* can override the method. In that case `self.task(20)` in a `SubTask` class will access `SubTask.task(20)`.

Comment: That depends on the intended use - `self` will always refer to the current instances' methods and will persist not only through the inheritance chain (compared to calling by a class name, i.e. `Test.task()`), picking up the latest override, even a dynamic one, while referring by class type will always point to the actual class method. Nothing stops you from setting `your_instance.task = some_dynamic_override` and then `self.task()` will be calling that function.

Comment: wouldnt it be the first one considering that self.__class__ would create an object while the first one is a direct call?

Comment: @xgord  I want to know that both ways are same or not, if not then what is differences and when I use first type or second method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`self.task(10)` is definitely the best.

First, both will ultimately end in same operation for class instances:

- __class__ is a special attribute that is guaranteed to exist for an class instance object and is is the class of the object (Ref: [Python reference manual / Data model / The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html))

> Class instances 
> ...
> Special attributes: __dict__ is the attribute dictionary; __class__ is the instance’s class

- calling a classmethod with a class instance object actually pass the class of the object to the method (Ref: same chapter of ref. manual):

> ...When an instance method object is created by retrieving a class method object from a class or instance, its __self__ attribute is the class itself

But the first is simpler and does not require usage of a special attribute.